# html picture with blue lines in outlook

Tags: html, outlook

For our company I'm creating emailsignatures (using an html code in Cloudpages for work), it works perfectly fine in gmail & Apple mail, but when you open an email in Outlook (send from Gmail in browser or Apple mail) blue lines appear around the picture.

How can I remove those blue lines?

[printscreen blue lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGlYB.png)

```
    <!-- [if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table border="0" width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;" valign="bottom">$!photoUrl$!photoUrl<img src="$!photoUrl" alt="Foto" width="132" height="160" /></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;" align="left" valign="bottom">
<table style="width: 275px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #0791a6; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 1px;"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 8px;" valign="top"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" /></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 15px !important;" align="left" valign="top" width="140">
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 15px !important;"><span style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 15px !important; color: #000001;"> <span style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 15px !important;"> <!-- START NAAM --> <strong style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 15px !important;">$personalName $personalSurname</strong><br /><em style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 15px !important;">$orgJobTitle</em><br /><br /> <!-- EINDE NAAM --> </span> </span></p>
</td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 10px;" valign="top"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="10" height="1" /></td>
<td style="background-color: #0791a6; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 1px;"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 8px;" valign="top"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" /></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 107px;" align="left" valign="top"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logo-vka.gif" alt="Logo VKA" width="107" height="54" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #0791a6; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 8px;" valign="top"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" /></td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;" align="left" valign="bottom">
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;"><span style="text-decoration: none; color: #000001;"> <!-- START TELEFOON --> #if ($phoneMobile !="")<span style="color: #000001 !important;"><span style="color: #000001;">M $phoneMobile</span></span>#end <br /><span style="color: #000001 !important;"><span style="color: #000001;">T +31 79 368 10 00</span></span><br /> <a style="color: #000001 !important;" href="https://www.vka.nl/?utm_source=emailhandtekening" target="_blank"><span style="color: #000001 !important;"><span style="color: #000001;">www.vka.nl</span></span></a> <!-- EINDE TELEFOON --> </span></p>
</td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 10px;" valign="top"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="10" height="1" /></td>
<td style="background-color: #0791a6; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 8px;" valign="top"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="8" height="1" /></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; width: 70px;" align="left" valign="bottom"><!-- START SOCIAL MEDIA -->
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; height: 28px; width: 34px;"><a title="LinkedIn" href="$!linkedin"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-linkedin.gif" alt="LinkedIn" width="34" height="28" border="0" /></a></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; height: 28px; width: 73px;"><a title="Twitter" href="$!twitter"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-twitter.gif" alt="Twitter" width="34" height="28" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- EINDE SOCIAL MEDIA --></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table border="0" width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; height: 18px;"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="1" height="18" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; height: 32px;" align="left">
<table border="0" width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; height: 8px; background-color: #f6db30; padding: 0;" height="8"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="1" height="8" /></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; height: 8px; width: 8px; padding: 0; background-color: #f6db30;" align="left" valign="top" height="8"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/hoekje-boven.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="gelebalk" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; height: 8px; background-color: #f6db30; text-align: center; padding: 0;" align="center"><!-- START LINK -->
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; font-weight: bold;"><a style="text-decoration: underline; color: #000001 !important;" href="https://www.vka.nl/privacy-podcast/?utm_source=emailhandtekening&amp;utm_medium=vka" target="_blank"><span style="color: #000001 !important;"><span style="color: #000001;">Ontdek onze Privacy Podcast in iTunes</span></span></a></p>
<!-- EINDE LINK --></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; width: 8px; background-color: #f6db30; padding: 0;" align="left" height="8"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; height: 8px; background-color: #f6db30; padding: 0;" height="8"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/transpunt.gif" alt="" width="1" height="8" /></td>
<td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0 !important; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; height: 8px; width: 8px; padding: 0; background-color: #f6db30;" align="left" valign="bottom" height="8"><img src="https://www.vka.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/hoekje-onder.gif" alt="" width="8" height="8" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p style="color: #ffffff;"><br /><br />.</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding border="0" to the img?

Comment: Yes, I have. There is one big blue line above the picture, and a small one on the left down side of the picture... (so not the entire border)

Comment: Please post your code and maybe a small screenshot.

Comment: Thanks! I added the printscreen of the blue lines and a printscreen of the first part of the code in the question (code is too long to post here..)

Comment: Don't post code in an image please. Paste it in a "code tag" (the `{}` button) to be readable. If it is too long, try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Now please reduce the code to just show the problem.

Comment: I guess the problem occurs in the first part of the code (I reduced the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not seeing blue lines, I think you're seeing tiny blue text. What you're seeing is a very tiny version of this: `$!photoUrl$!photoUrl`. I think Outlook is ignoring the `font-size:0;` and possibly not processing the second URL you are adding to your code before the image.

You didn't post all of your code, but what you did post has a few issues. You didn't close the table, you didn't close the href you started before the image.

To make your table function better in Outlook, I added a few style classes that help make Outlook display a table in a better manner: `border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;`.

I added a style attribute `display: block;` which helps Outlook better display an image.

Try this code instead:

```
<!-- [if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
  <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]-->
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table border="0" width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 0 !important; border-collapse: collapse;" valign="bottom">
        <a href="$!photoUrl" target="_blank">
            <img src="$!photoUrl" alt="Foto" width="132" height="160" border="0" style="display: block;" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Let me know the results.

Good luck.

Comment: It was tiny blue text! It was the $!photoUrl$!photoUrl (so it showed the url's in Outlook), I removed it from the code and now it works :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of the blue line by adding text-decoration:none in the parent element.

Before:

```html
<p>
    <img src="..." />
<p>
```

After

```html
<p style="text-decoration:none;">
    <img src="..." />
</p>
```